# How to add 2 different animals into a text file using inheritance, if they have different constructors?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I'm trying to use inheritance to add 2 different animals into a text file, a cat and dog. Problem is, they have different constructors and I'm not sure how to put them into the program seperately into the same text file, because the program also uses a user interface.

Comment: Do you mean to say the the input file could contain 2 different animals?

Comment: Yes, but with only one or 2 different constructor values, most of them are the same such as the name of the animal and its favourite food, but they have different booleans, so I'm not sure how to add them to the text file together with their different constructors, as the user interface would have to change or something, and I don't know how to create the seperate arraylists as that wouldn't be inheritance if I had one for cats and one for dogs.

Comment: try to put only the relevant part of the code, more readable = more response

Comment: What you wanted sounds easy enough. It is all about the basics of Java. Do you want different animals to be written in the same text file or different text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure If I understood your question.

You have a text file where dogs and cats infos are written. You want to pass them into your program. 
Is that text file is in your control? When you start to read it from it, can you understand is it a cat or dog at start? Like 
`animal type: cat`
`animal name: fluffy` 
...
if so:

```
int numAnimals = infile.nextInt();
infile.nextLine();
kennel.setName(kennelName);
for (int i = 0; i < numAnimals; i++) {
  if(infile.nextLine().equals("cat")) {
    Cat cat = readCat(infile);
    kennel.addAnimals(cat);
}
  else if(infile.nextLine().equals("dog")){
    Dog dog = readDog(infile);
    kennel.addAnimals(dog);
}
}

public Dog readDog(Scanner infile) {
  //same as your dog reading part except the last part
  return new Dog(animalName, owners, likesBones, favFood,
      feedsPerDay);
}
```

Write same method for cats and there you go. Since Dog class is inherited from animal class, dog is also an animal. Therefore you can add it to your animal list as an animal. Hope this is helped.

Comment: No, the program writes to the text file, when the user enters the different values into the interface the program sends that information to the text file. And yes I'm in control of that text file, I've formatted it so the values appear on different lines. Yes, I've just been working on adding an animal type, there wasn't one before.

Comment: Okay, in any case my answer should satisfy you I guess? Let me know if you still have problem.